# OpenGL rotation?

Tags: opengl

I'm writing an simple application based on openGL and qt. It creates primitive (triangle for example) which rotation user can change by using one of three spinboxes 
(coordinates: x, y, z). The problem is local coordinate system. It changes and works properly for axes Y and Z but not for X. Local axis X always coincides with global axis X. So when i rotate my figure by 90' around Y then axes X and Z are parallel because local Z changed (as I expected) and local X didn't change. Here is fragment of my paintGL() function:

- glRotatef(rot[0], 1.0, 0, 0);
- glRotatef(rot[1], 0, 1.0, 0);
- glRotatef(rot[2], 0, 0, 1.0);

Comment: You're going to need to post all the relevant code. As it is, the above code is fine, but you could be potentially running into Gimbal lock. What are the values of rot[0], rot[1], and rot[2]?

Comment: what does your code look like?
the problem of local axes transforming can be solved with glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() methods.
check out chapter 3 from OpenGL SuperBible 4th edition.

Answer (score 0):

You should use rotation matrix which lets you specify rotation axis and angles of rotation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

Generally it is not a good idea to perform rotations with euler angles: the next problem you will come around is the 180 deg. flip in certain angle constellations. The problem is broadly known as [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) with euler angles.

Comment: The rotations should be expressed with quaternions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion